# Find preceding and following rows for a matching row in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

Is it possible to find rows preceding and following a matching rows in a BigQuery query? For example if I do:

```
select textPayload from logs.logs_20160709 where textPayload like "%something%"
```

and say that I get these results back:

```
something A
something B
```

How can I also show the 3 rows *preceding* and *following* the matching rows? Something like this:

```
some text 1
some text 2
some text 3
something A
some text 4
some text 5
some text 6
some text 90
some text 91
some text 92
something B
some text 93
some text 94
some text 95
```

Is this possible and if so how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While on Zuma Beach - I was thinking of avoiding CROSS JOIN in my original answer.
Check below - should be `much cheaper` especially for big set

```
SELECT textPayload
FROM (
  SELECT textPayload, 
    SUM(match) OVER(ORDER BY ts ROWS BETWEEN 3 PRECEDING AND 3 FOLLOWING) AS flag
  FROM (
    SELECT textPayload, ts,  IF(textPayload CONTAINS 'something', 1, 0) AS match 
    FROM YourTable
  )
)
WHERE flag > 0
```

*Of course another way to avoid cross join is to use BigQuery Standard SQL. But still - above solution with no joins at all is better than my original answer*

Answer (score 0):

I think, one piece is missing in your example  - extra field that will define the order, so I added ts field for this in my answer. This mean I assume your table has two fields involved : textPayload and ts

Try below. Should give you exactly what you need

```
SELECT 
  all.textPayload
FROM (
  SELECT start, finish
  FROM (
    SELECT textPayload,
      LAG(ts, 3) OVER(ORDER BY ts ROWS BETWEEN 3 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS start, 
      LEAD(ts, 3) OVER(ORDER BY ts ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 3 FOLLOWING) AS finish
    FROM YourTable
  )
  WHERE textPayload CONTAINS 'something'
) AS matches
CROSS JOIN YourTable AS all
WHERE all.ts BETWEEN matches.start AND matches.finish
```

Please note: depends on type of your ts field - you might need to do some data casting in query for this field. hope not